# Getting error when getting data from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I Have a Jquery Drop Upload form all working good but when i'm trying to get data from database with json its working but i don't know why its showing error. please check below for more infromation

**my error**

```
jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in [{"name":"1.xlsx","size":34838},{"name":"485138_1.xlsx","size":34838}]
at s (jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:2)
at Function.each (jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:2)
at Object.success (misupload.js:111)
at j (jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:2)
at x (jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:4)
```

**Here is my js code**

```
$.get('/resumes/mis-upload-get-action?_act=bulk', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key,value){
        var mockFile = { name: value.name, size: value.size};
        thisDropzone.options.addedfile.call(thisDropzone, mockFile);
        totalFiles += 1;
        completeFiles += 1;
    });
    $('.btn-proceed .badge').html(totalFiles);
});
```

**Here is my server side json code**

```
[{"name":"1.xlsx","size":34838},{"name":"485138_1.xlsx","size":34838}]
```

Please Help me OUT

Comment: Try `$.getJSON` instead. That will parse the data properly for you. I think you get that error when you try and use `each` on a string. Alternatively, `JSON.parse(data)` the data before you iterate over it.

Comment: Ok but whats is error with this code i want to know

Comment: what `console.log(data)` reveals?

Comment: try console.log(typeof(data))

Comment: Please specify `when i'm trying to get data from database with json its working but i don't know why its showing error`. That it is working, but still shows an error, sounds paradox.

Comment: what is mean here leanth `Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in`

Comment: Its getting data from data base but error in my js

Comment: @Deepak, did you try what I suggested? Maybe you won't get the error if you make one of those changes.

Comment: That error means jQuery is trying to iterate over something that it can't iterate over - in this case a string. It's looking for an array or an object.

Comment: in operator is used by js

Comment: The `in` operator is used by JavaScript @FirasOmrane.

Answer (score 1):

That error means jQuery is trying to iterate over something that it can't iterate over - in this case a string. You need to parse your data in order for jQuery to iterate over it.

You can do this either by using `$.getJSON` (jQuery will automatically parse your data to an object), or by using  `JSON.parse(data)`.

Answer (score -1):

try using .emit()

```
$.get('/resumes/mis-upload-get-action?_act=bulk', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key,value){
        var mockFile = { name: value.name, size: value.size};
        thisDropzone.emit("addedfile", mockFile);
        thisDropzone.emit("complete", mockFile);
        totalFiles += 1;
        completeFiles += 1;
    });
    $('.btn-proceed .badge').html(totalFiles);
});
```

Let me know if it helps

Comment: Its Not Working

Comment: @Deepak, did you try the suggestions I made in my first comment?

Comment: Yes Andy Its working but i'm a beginner so i want to know buy its not working

Comment: @Deepak what does your dropzone initialization look like, parsing the data should work just fine like suggested. The reason for your error is probably because the data couldnt be looped over in whatever from it is originally presented in.

Comment: @Deepak, I _told_ you why it's not working in a subsequent comment.

Comment: You could probably just use a for loop rather than an $.each to avoid confusion, since youre a beginner as you said